# How to sum columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sum

I am trying to create a column that is the total value of column A,B,C,D,E.

```
 select,[TVIncome] a
  ,[XIncome] b
  ,[ZIncome] c
  ,[DINCOME] d
  ,[OIncome] e
```

sum(a,b,c,d,e) as total

The error I get when doing the above sum is :"The sum function requires 1 argument(s)."

The total above does not work. Also, if I just include the the proper names, XIncome and the rest,it still does not work. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUM()` adds each value in a column, to give a single value
`+` adds each value in two columns together to give a column

It sounds like you are after `a + b + c + d + e AS total`, 
or possibly `SUM(a + b + c + d + e) AS total` if you are after 1 value

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want a sum for those columns for each row

```
SELECT (TVIncome + XIncome + ZIncome + DIncome + OIncome) as TotalIncome
FROM Table
```

If you want a sum of sums, which will equal one row:

```
SELECT SUM(TVIncome + XIncome + ZIncome + DIncome  + OIncome) as TotalIncome
FROM Table
```